# Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline task DownloadPipelineArtifact keeps failing to download items

Tags: azure-devops

I have a YAML Pipeline with two stages, build_stage and deploy_stage.

Build Stage will publish the artifact.

```
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'
      parallel: true
    displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact: drop'
```

Deploy Stage will download the artifact.

```
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      artifact: drop
```

This task (`DownloadPipelineArtifact`) is currently taking more than 60 minutes to execute and being killed because many, many downloads fail and have to be retried.

```
2023-05-03T01:54:21.1997791Z Verbose, Downloaded /APIM/APIManagementPolicies/OBRD/RT-SYD-ICC-logic-obrd-smo-putFeatures-operation-policy.xml
2023-05-03T01:54:21.1998640Z Verbose, Downloaded /APIM/Templates/RT-SYD-NPE-ICC-APM-apiTags.template.json
2023-05-03T01:54:21.1999251Z Verbose, Downloaded /APIM/APIManagementPolicies/OBRD/obrd-smo-API-Policy.xml
2023-05-03T01:54:21.1999972Z Verbose, Downloaded /OBRD/Functions/rt-syd-npe-dev-icc-obrd-storage-fa/Properties/ServiceDependencies/rt-syd-npe-dev-icc-obrd-storage-fa - Zip Deploy/appInsights1.arm.json
2023-05-03T01:54:21.2001337Z Verbose, [https://avhvsblobprodeau140.blob.core.windows.net/REDACTED/REDACTED?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2023-05-04T02:32:53Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-REDACTED-session-REDACTED] Try 1/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:01. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
2023-05-03T01:54:21.2002786Z  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
2023-05-03T01:54:21.2003545Z  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

The downloads generally succeed on a retry.

What's happening here that causes the SSL connection randomly fail to be established?

Comment: is it mainly failing on artifacts from azure storage? it looks like storage accounts are still default Minimum TLS Version 1.0.  Try bumping Azure Storage -> Configuration -> Min TLS to Version 1.2

Comment: Not sure sorry, the URL looks like it might be backed by Azure Storage but the "upload" is just the standard `PublishPipelineArtifact` step. Also, the downloads of smaller individual files all succeed so it seems unlikely to be TLS?

Comment: Did your network rules on the storage account change? This seems like maybe your storage account firewall is messing with your builds.